# How do I degloss my shiny bike?

Tags: paint

I have a Tomasso Sterrata.

I love the bike, but I don't love the paint job.
[image: bike image]
I think I would like the paint job more if it weren't so *glossy*. ([*This year's* model](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004P69XWG) has a matte finish of course, but I have *last year's model.*)

What can I do to give it a more matte finish without covering up the existing color and decals?

Comment: Find some dirt and go mad.

Comment: There are various deglossing sprays available, stuff that goes on like varnish.  You might ask at an auto parts place that carries a lot of auto paint products.  Or at a hobby shop, where paint for various model trains, etc, is sold.

Comment: you could also use a matte clear coat directly over the glossy clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to paint it, you can try to wetsand it to remove the clear coat, and then refinish it with some matt finish clear coat. This is a risky move if you're not experienced with painting cars or stuff. You can ruin your bike real quick.

The safe method, and easiest one, would be to wrap the bike with some matt/satin finish clear vinyl ([here is an example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BKVQ0ZG)). It is often used on cars by people with the same issue as yours, and would perfectly do the trick on your bike. Plus you can remove it whenever you want, and it will protect your frame. It's a win-win.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to make the bike less glossy is to scuff the clearcoat a bit. It won't give it a nice matte look, but rather a "broken-in" well-used appearance.

Use fine steel wool (0000) and rub the frame in circular motions. It's an inexpensive, simpler method for making your bike less shiny, but may not be the look you're going for. As long as you don't overdo it the damage to the clearcoat should be minimal.